# What is this bicycle I’m not sure what it is

Tags: identify-this-bike

Not a bicycle person and not sure what this is.[image]

Comment: We would probably need more pictures to help out.  Any identifying marks, especially a logo on the headtube, and components, if there are any.

Comment: The bike is a "department store" model, almost certainly from the 50s.  The chain guard looks very much like the Sears guard from that era.

Comment: what information are you actually looking for here?

Answer (score 14):

It looks like a classic [electro-forged](https://rode-bike.com/schwinn-electro-forged-frames/) Schwinn frame.
The fenders, chain guard, chain ring and seat match the 1952 Standard Schwinn for Girls.

[image]
[waterfordbikes.com 1952_04](https://waterfordbikes.com/SchwinnCat/flschwinn_1951_1960/1952_04.html)

Or the 1953 Schwinn Meteor for Girls
[image]
[waterfordbikes.com 1953_02](https://waterfordbikes.com/SchwinnCat/flschwinn_1951_1960/1953_02.html)

Schwinn used the same frame for several different models within a year and over the years. The models were made different by adding a tank or lights or a rack.
1957 was the last year for the support bar between the top tube and the down tube.